# How to force DistributionChart to plot empty datasets?

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts

Is there any way to force `DistributionChart` to display **anything** where there is an empty dataset? In the below example I'd like to have `0`-s appearing where data is missing, but even a simple `Point` would be sufficient as that can be labeled.

The problem is that `ChartElementFunction` is not applied to empty datasets and thus `Labeled` wrappers are also ignored. Furthermore, `ChartLabels` (or association keys) cannot be forced to use different sub-labels for successive sets (it's always `s1, s2, s3`). I'd rather avoid reconstructing coordinates to use with `Epilog` (I've tried and failed with more complex `BarSpacing` values) or extract tick coordinates from `InputForm[plot]` or reconstruct built-in `ChartElementFunction`s (see `ChartElementData@DistributionChart`), as these methods are not very robust.

```
data = <|
   "D1" -> <|"s1" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "s2" -> Labeled[{}, "Empty", Center],
             "s3" -> {3, 4, 5, 6}|>,
   "D2" -> <|"s1" -> {}, "s2" -> {}, "s3" -> {}|>,
   "D3" -> <|"s1" -> {3, 4}, "s2" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, "s3" -> {}|>,
   "D4" -> <|"s1" -> {1, 2}, "s2" -> {3, 4}, "s3" -> {5, 6}|>
   |>;

plot = DistributionChart[Map[Labeled[#, Length@#, Below] &, data, {2}],
 BarSpacing -> {.2, 1}, ChartLabels -> Automatic,
 ChartElementFunction -> "Density"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Does replacing `{} ` with `{0,0}` (i.e.,`data2=data /. {}->{0,0}`) work?

Comment: I think DistributionChart need to have a non empty list to set the lower and upper boundary of the chart. As kguler mentioned, you can also try data2=data /. {}->{n,n})  with any real n.

Comment: @kguler Sure, I can do that, but  it would not be rubust: what if my distribution has the expected value of 0? Than I had to replace `{}` with something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** a custom `ChartElementFunction` that can be combined with built-in `ChartElementFunction`s:

```
ceF2[cedf_: ChartElementDataFunction["Density"]][vpos_: {0, 0}] := If[#3 == {"empty"}, 
 {PointSize[Large], Point[Mean@Transpose@{#[[1]],vpos}]}, cedf[##]] &
```

Examples: using a dataset that does not require version 10 functions

```
SeedRandom[1]
datac = {{RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[5], 30], 
    Labeled[{}, "Empty", Center], 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 50]}, {{}, {}, {0, 
     0}}, {RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[3], 50], 
    RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 100], {}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}};


vp0 = Min[datac /. Labeled | Style -> (#1 &)];
DistributionChart[Map[Labeled[# /. {} | Labeled[{}, __] :>
    ((vp = {vp0 - 1, vp0 - 1}) -> "empty"), 
    Length[# /. Labeled -> (# &)], Below] &, datac, {2}], 
 BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], BarSpacing -> {.2, 1}, 
 ChartLabels -> {"s1", "s2", "s3"}, ChartStyle -> 63, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF2[][vp], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use

```
ChartElementFunction -> 
 ceF2[ChartElementDataFunction["GlassQuantile", "Quantile" -> 10, 
    "QuantileShading" -> True]][vp]
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Original post:**

Your `data` modified to have both `{}` and `{0,0}` elements as well as elements with zero mean:

```
datab= <|"D1" -> <|"s1" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "s2" -> Labeled[{}, "Empty", Center],
             "s3" -> {-3,-2,2,3}|>,
   "D2" -> <|"s1" -> {}, "s2" -> {}, "s3" -> {0,0}|>,
   "D3" -> <|"s1" -> {3, 4}, "s2" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, "s3" -> {}|>,
   "D4" -> <|"s1" -> {1, 2}, "s2" -> {3, 4}, "s3" -> {5, 6}|>
   |>;
```

Use metadata to distinguish empty sets, and modify the `ChartElementFunction` to render empty sets as `Point`s:

```
vp0 = Min[datab /. Labeled|Style->(#&)];
DistributionChart[Map[Labeled[#/.{}|Labeled[{},__]:>
   ((vp={vp0-1,vp0-1})->"empty"), 
   Length[# /.  Labeled ->(#&)], Below] &, datab, {2}],
 BarSpacing -> {.2, 1},ChartLabels ->{"s1", "s2" , "s3" },
ChartElementFunction -> (If[#3 == {"empty"},   
   {PointSize[Large],Point[Mean@Transpose@{#[[1]],vp}]},
   Rectangle @@ Transpose@#1] &)
]
```

[image]

Or define a custom `ChartElementDataFunction`

```
ceF[vpos_:{0,0}]:=If[#3 == {"empty"}, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[Mean@Transpose@{#[[1]],vpos}]}, Rectangle@@Transpose@#1] &
```

and use as

```
DistributionChart[Map[Labeled[#/.{}|Labeled[{},__]:>
   ((vp={vp0-1,vp0-1})->"empty"), 
   Length[#/.  Labeled[{},__]:>{}], Below] &, datab, {2}],
 BarSpacing -> {.2, 1}, ChartLabels ->{"s1", "s2" , "s3" },
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF[vp]
]
```

(* same picture *)

Comment: Ok, this is even better but it fails when one wants to use built-in chart elements, like `"PointDensity"`, etc. Yes, I forgot to include this in my post (sorry about that), modified now.

Comment: @Istvan, just added a variant of `ceF` that takes built-in `ChartElementFunction`s as input.

Comment: Yes, this really pointed me to the right direction, thanks! Previously I failed to figure out how to pass on built-in CEFunctions to my own `cef`.

Comment: @Istvan, thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 5):

Would this work for you? I need to assume the data can be transformed into

```
xData = 
   <|"D1" -> <|"s1" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "s2" -> {0, 0}, "s3" -> {3, 4, 5, 6}|>, 
     "D2" -> <|"s1" -> {0, 0}, "s2" -> {0, 0}, "s3" -> {0, 0}|>, 
     "D3" -> <|"s1" -> {3, 4}, "s2" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, "s3" -> {0, 0}|>, 
     "D4" -> <|"s1" -> {1, 2}, "s2" -> {3, 4}, "s3" -> {5, 6}|>|>
```

Then the a distribution chart that indicates zero data items where the inner associations have value `{0, 0}`, can be drawn with

```
plot = DistributionChart[
  Map[Labeled[#, If[# == {0, 0}, 0, Length @ #], Below] &, xData, {2}],
  BarSpacing -> {.2, 1},
  ChartLabels -> Automatic,
  ChartElementFunction -> ((Rectangle @@ Transpose @ #) &)]
```

[image: chart]

Note: the original data can transformed in the form I use here with

```
xdata = data /. _Labeled -> {} /. {} -> {0, 0};
```

Comment: +1, really nice trick (I feel ashamed that I have not thought of this).