# BarChart with empty bars removed

Tags: plotting, charts

Consider the following `BarChart`:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {None, 2, None}, {1, None, 5}},
         ChartLegends -> {"A", "B", "C"},
         ChartLabels -> {{"X", "Y", "Z"}, None},
         LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Row[{"", #}], Bottom] &),
         BarSpacing -> None, AxesLabel -> "l"]
```

How can the empty bars be removed to save space with the appropriate coloring/labels maintained?

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related, but for the reverse purpose: [How to force DistributionChart to plot empty datasets?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81092/89).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *metadata* form of `BarChart`'s data elements, $\text{form}_i\to m_i$, to specify the bar colour when a category is omitted. You do have to specify the colours in `ChartStyle` as well.

```
data = {{1,2,3},{None,2,None},{1,None,5}};

BarChart[
 First@MapThread[
   Thread@*Rule,
   {
    {data /. None -> Nothing},
    {Pick[{Orange, Brown, Blue}, #, True] & /@ 
      Map[NumericQ, data, {2}]}
    }, 2]
 ,
 ChartStyle -> {Orange, Brown, Blue},
 ChartLegends -> {"A", "B", "C"},
 ChartLabels -> {{"X", "Y", "Z"}, None}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Row[{"", #}], Bottom] &), 
 BarSpacing -> None, AxesLabel -> "l"]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use RectangleChart for this purpose. First you need to make a new data set which contains the widths of each bar. Here's the data manipulation:

```
data = {{1,2,3},{None,2,None},{1,None,5}};
data2 = data /. None->0
data3 = Table[{HeavisideTheta[data2[[i, j]] - 0.1], data2[[i, j]]},
{i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
```

The HeavisideTheta function gives each bar unit width unless it was originally "None"

```
RectangleChart[data3, ChartLegends -> {"A", "B", "C"}, 
ChartLabels -> {{"X", "Y", "Z"}, None}, 
LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Row[{"", #[[2]]/.(0)->""}], Bottom] &), 
BarSpacing -> None, AxesLabel -> "l"]
```

EDIT: Following @Kuba's suggestion, the list manipulation can be more elegantly done using

```
datanew = Map[{1, #} /. {_, None} -> {0, 0} &, data, {2}]
```

...and inserting this into the first argument of the RectangleChart function above

Comment: `/. (0) -> ""`  () are missing

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. Actually, it seems either /.(0)->"" or /. 0->"" [i.e. with a space] works. I appreciate this is a bit of a hack. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: That's nice solution, consider `Map[{1, #} /. {_, None} -> {0, 0} &, data, {2}]`.

Answer (score 0):

Color each data point using `Style` and remove the non-numeric data points:

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {None, 2, None}, {1, None, 5}};
colors = ColorData[59, "ColorList"][[;; Length@data[[1]]]];
styleddata = Style @@@ (Thread[{#, colors}]) & /@ data /. Style[ None, __] :> (## &[]);

BarChart[styleddata, ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[59, {"A", "B", "C"}],
 ChartLabels -> {{"X", "Y", "Z"}, None},
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Row[{"", #}], Bottom] &), BarSpacing -> None]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
data2 = RandomChoice[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4} -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None}, {5, 6}];
colors = ColorData[54, "ColorList"][[;; Length@data2[[1]]]];
styleddata = Style @@@ (Thread[{#, colors}]) & /@ data2 /. Style[ None, __] :> (## &[]);

BarChart[styleddata, 
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[54, CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; Length @ data2[[1]]]]],
 ChartLabels -> {{"X", "Y", "Z", "W", "V"}, None},
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Row[{"", #}], Bottom] &), BarSpacing -> None]
```

[image]